# Apigee TargetServer fails to configure for SSL

Tags: apigee

I am trying to configure one of the TargetServers to talk HTTPS to the backend service.  Per [Apigee's official documentation](http://docs.apigee.com/api-services/content/load-balancing-across-backend-servers#configuringatargetserverforssl) as well as [other sources](https://community.apigee.com/answers/8514/view.html), it should be as easy as adding `SSLInfo` node to the TargetServer definition, and in that node set `"enabled" : true`.  I am sending a `PUT` call to accomplish just that, but the response comes back without `SSLInfo` node.  Following up with `GET` confirms that `SSLInfo` node is not there.

Request (redacted)

```
PUT /v1/organizations/---/environments/---/targetservers/Services HTTP/1.1
Host: ---
Content-Type: application/json
Authorization: Basic ---
Cache-Control: no-cache

{
  "name" : "Services",
  "host" : "---",
  "isEnabled" : true,
  "port" : 443,
  "SSLInfo": {
    "enabled": true
  }
}
```

With Response (redacted), and same if followed up with `GET`

```
{
  "host": "qa-services.ignitionone.com",
  "isEnabled": true,
  "name": "Services",
  "port": 443
}
```

As you can see, the `SSLInfo` just doesn't stick, and thus fails to enable Edge-to-Target HTTPS communication.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 1):

Ok, the issue turned out to be JSON serializer being very case-sensitive.  It is not `"SSLInfo"` but rather MUST be `"sSLInfo"`.  It started working after making the capitalization change.

So full structure that worked:

```
PUT /v1/organizations/---/environments/---/targetservers/Services HTTP/1.1
Host: ---
Content-Type: application/json
Authorization: Basic ---
Cache-Control: no-cache

{
  "name" : "Services",
  "host" : "---",
  "isEnabled" : true,
  "port" : 443,
  "sSLInfo": {
    "enabled": true
  }
}
```